# Segmentation fault error in C when trying to print to a file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I created a function which is supposed to to get a binary tree in argument, a filename in user input and inside that file print the binary tree in order to be later converted into a picture via graphviz.

The binary tree type provided is:

```
struct noeud_s;

typedef struct noeud_s noeud;

typedef noeud* arbre;

struct noeud_s{
  char* valeur;
  arbre gauche;
  arbre droit;
};
```

The 2 functions I created are:

```
void create_dot(arbre racine)
{
  FILE *f;
  char file_name[100];
  printf ("Nom du fichier a creer (Ajouter .dot a la fin): ");
  scanf ("%s", file_name);
  printf("Name: %s\n", file_name);
  printf ("Creation du fichier dot\n");
  f = fopen(file_name, "w");
  if (f == NULL)
  {
    printf("NULL\n");
  }
  fprintf(f, "digigraph tree {\n");
  write_to_dot(f, racine);
  fprintf(f, "}");
  fclose(f);
}

void write_to_dot(FILE *f, arbre racine)
{
  if (racine == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }
  if (racine != NULL)
  {
    fprintf(f, "%s -> %s [label = \"non\"]\n", racine -> valeur, racine -> gauche -> valeur);
    fprintf(f, "%s -> %s [label = \"oui\"]\n", racine -> valeur, racine -> droit -> valeur);
    write_to_dot(f, racine -> gauche);
    write_to_dot(f, racine -> droit);
  }
  return;
}
```

As far as debugging goes, I have deducted that my segmentation fault happens inside the write_to_dot function. But because I can't properly handle gdb, I would like you to help me find my segmentation fault and explain it please.

Comment: You are dereferencing a null pointer here: `fprintf(f, "%s -> %s [label = \"non\"]\n", racine -> valeur, racine -> gauche -> valeur);`  **-->>** `fprintf, "%s -> %s [label = \"non\"]\n", racine->valeur, rachine->gauche ? racine->gauche->valeur" : "Jamais!" );`

Comment: If you can run your program under `gdb`, you can enter commands like `print racine`, `print racine->valeur`, `print racine->gauche`, and so on. This will likely pinpoint the problem quickly. We can't do that because we have no idea how your code is calling `create_dot`. Likely the problem is in the value passed for `racine` and what it points to.

Comment: "But because I can't properly handle gdb" - then this would be an *excellent* opportunity for you to learn how to properly handle gdb. "Teach a man to fish" and all that stuff.

Comment: If I may, the `typedef noeud* arbre;` ... I would like to suggest that typedef-ing pointer types to another name just confuses things.  Unless of course "arbre" just means "pointer-to"

Comment: @Kingsley I know that it's confusing but I have no choise. I was given that as a type definition and I can't change it

Comment: @SotirisKettenis - OK. Unfortunately silly specifications are sometimes part of the job.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is printing out a binary tree.  There is no code showing how nodes are constructed, but in typical binary trees, the leaf nodes have `NULL` left & right child-nodes (or `gauche` and `droit` as it were).

The function `write_to_dot` will fail at the first leaf-node (if not at the empty-side of an intermediate branch-node), because `racine->gauche` and `racine->droit` would be `NULL`, yet they are still de-referenced - `racine->gauche->valeur` without any checking.

While I don't have all the code, at least testing for this condition will solve one of the issues:

```
void write_to_dot ( FILE *f, arbre racine )
{
    if ( racine != NULL )
    {
        if (racine->gauche != NULL)
            fprintf ( f, "%s -> %s [label = \"non\"]\n", racine->valeur, racine->gauche->valeur );
        else
            fprintf ( f, "%s -> NULL [label = \"non\"]\n", racine->valeur );

        if (racine->droit != NULL)
            fprintf ( f, "%s -> %s [label = \"oui\"]\n", racine->valeur, racine->droit->valeur );
        else
            fprintf ( f, "%s -> NULL [label = \"oui\"]\n", racine->valeur );

        write_to_dot ( f, racine->gauche );
        write_to_dot ( f, racine->droit );
    }
}
```